# How to use multiple urls in a python program

Tags: awk, sed

I am using a tool named https://github.com/epinna/tplmap which tests for Template Injection in a site. This is how it test for each url

> python tplmap.py -u https://leadform.microsoft.com/?lang=FUZZ

Developer has not included option for multiple urls
How can i use awk/sed/cat to add multiple urls from a text file?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: cat line-appss2.txt | xargs -I % python

Answer (score 0):

> Developer has not included option for multiple urls

I have look at [`tplmap.py`](https://github.com/epinna/tplmap/blob/master/tplmap.py) and it seems viable to alterting so it would work as you wish, thing which needs change is function named `main` which looks as follows

```
def main():
    
    args = vars(cliparser.options)
    
    if not args.get('url'):
        cliparser.parser.error('URL is required. Run with -h for help.')
        
    # Add version
    args['version'] = version
    
    checks.check_template_injection(Channel(args))
```

what is happening here: `args` dict is created based on command line arguments, presence of `url` checked, `version` added and checking function called. I would alter that function to

```
def main():
    
    args = vars(cliparser.options)
    
    if not args.get('url'):
        cliparser.parser.error('URL is required. Run with -h for help.')
        
    # Add version
    args['version'] = version
    url_filename = args['url']
    with open(url_filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            args['url'] = line.rstrip()
            checks.check_template_injection(Channel(args))
```

so now it does open file provided where url was earlier provided for each line it is `rstrip`-ped to jettison trailing newline and provided as `url` in `args` then check is run. Note: I did not test that code, please apply described change and first to try use it with file holding few addresses and check if it does what you want.